# My rig stretches and shrinks

Tags: rigging, bones, freestyle

I'll cut to the chase.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to make a stylized foot consisting of only bones and rigged it (so I can pose it later).
Now when I rotate my a_bones (in pose mode) my bones go slower than my a_bones and then proceed to shrink.

|

|

a_bones = armature bones

bones = mesh object

*I will upload the file to this question using blendexchange:*

[image]

Comment: Hi, Dries. **One** question at a time please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *Master* bone influences your whole mesh, so it conflicts with the influence of all the other bones. You can either:

- Select the whole mesh and in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Vertex Groups*, unlock the *Master* group and click on the *Remove* button.

[image]

- Or select the Master bone, go in the *Properties* panel > *Bone* > disable the *Deform* option.

[image]